# How to print (trace) within tensorflow's source code

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a small trial to print out something within tensorflow's kernel.

ex, I would like to print something within

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/GradientDescentOptimizer

Then I search for the corresponding sources in my laptop where Ubuntu 16.04 has been installed.

Below are what I found.

[image]

I think gradient_descent.py within either

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/optimizer_v2

or

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training

are used. Hence I modify them both.

However, I cannot see the modifications.

I wonder why it failed.

Is there any way the trace Tensorflow source code (I know C & C++ part needs to be re-compile so focus on Python now)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What modifications did you do? You can definitively find out the module in use by importing it in the shell: `import tensorflow as tf; tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` outputs `<class 'tensorflow.python.training.gradient_descent.GradientDescentOptimizer'>` for me.

Comment: I add some print; ex; just try print("show me!!") to check if I can dump something by this way, thx

Answer (score 2):

Check `CurrentStackTrace` API provided by [TensorFlow util](https://git.codingcafe.org/Mirrors/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/05386f42f18d66bf9ff1d69edf5c47591e60f804#7072d8e53ad79c876c4134d01590e6a7b14cb4f5_26_39).
An example use can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/compiler/xla/util.cc#L46).